# Batch script terminating unexpectedly before IF command

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I have written the below code in a batch script.

```
set /p timestamp=Enter timestamp:
cd "C:\temp\%timestamp%"
for %%a in (*.rmt) do (bldtool -c COMMAND -a SPLIT -n %%a -l C:\temp\%timestamp%)
if exist "C:\temp\%timestamp%\XCLES01A.c" (xcopy /Y "C:\Program Files\CA\AllFusion Gen\GEN\extrn\src\XCLES01A.c" "C:\temp\%timestamp%")
for %%a in (*.icm) do (bldtool -c COMMAND -a BUILD -n %%a -l C:\temp\%timestamp% -f CodeMgr)
pause
```

When i run the above script line-by-line in cmd, it runs as expected. However, when I run it in the form of a script, it terminates before the if command is executed i.e. the window just disappears.

I have spent hours on trying to resolve this and am still stuck. Please help ! I am very new to batch scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Update: BLDTOOL is an executable software.

Comment: Is `bldtool` a batch file? if it is, you need to use `call bldtool ....` so the execution returns to your calling code.

Comment: Hi could you tell us what "bldtool" is. Thank's.

Comment: Hi!! BLDTOOL is an executable software. However, I changed it to call BLDTOOL just to see if it works and it did!! Thank you!!

Comment: @user3331568 - that means BLDTOOL is actually a batch script (BLDTOOL.BAT or BLDTOOL.CMD) that probably launches an .exe program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I haven't though):

```
set /p timestamp=Enter timestamp:
cd /D "C:\temp\%timestamp%"

for %%a in (*.rmt) do (
  bldtool -c COMMAND -a SPLIT -n %%a -l "C:\temp\%timestamp%"
)

if exist "C:\temp\%timestamp%\XCLES01A.c" (
  xcopy /Y "C:\Program Files\CA\AllFusion Gen\GEN\extrn\src\XCLES01A.c" "C:\temp\%timestamp%"
)

for %%a in (*.icm) do (
  bldtool -c COMMAND -a BUILD -n %%a -l "C:\temp\%timestamp%" -f CodeMgr
)

pause
```